# How to make a Responsive Grid?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid, responsive

So I have a html and css with a specific grid, I already made the .css, but I'm missing something, normally its the col-md or col-sm into the html using bootstraps, but everytime that I tried still not working for all devices, can anyone helpe me?

```css
.container {  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 285px 285px 285px 400px;
    grid-template-rows: 142px 296px 259px 333px;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    gap: 5px 5px;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-areas:
      "A B C D"
      "E B C D"
      "F G H D"
      "I I I I";
    width: 1440px;
    height: 1239px;
  }
  
  .A {
    grid-area: A;
    width: 259px;
    height: 122px;
  }
  
  .B {
    grid-area: B;
    width: 259px;
    height: 416px;
  }
  
  .C {
    grid-area: C;
    width: 259px;
    height: 416px;
  }
  
  .D {
    grid-area: D;
    width: 380px;
    height: 668px;
  }
  
  .E {
    grid-area: E;
    width: 259px;
    height: 273.87px;
  }
  
  .F {
    grid-area: F;
    width: 259px;
    height: 230px;
  }
  
  .G {
    grid-area: G;
    width: 259px;
    height: 230px;
  }
  
  .H {
    grid-area: H;
    width: 259px;
    height: 230px;
  }
  
  .I {
    grid-area: I;
    width: 1252px;
    height: 335px;
  }
  
  
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  
  .container * {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .container *:after {
    content:attr(class);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
 

  @media (min-width: 575.98px) { 
    .container { grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr); }

   }

@media (min-width: 767.98px) { 
    .container { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }

 }

@media (min-width: 991.98px) { 
    .container { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }

 }

@media (min-width: 1199.98px) { 
    .container { grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); }

 }

@media (min-width: 1399.98px) { 
    .container { grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); }

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>This is a example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dashboard.css"> 
</head>
<body>
    
      <section class="content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="A"></div>
          <div class="B"></div>
          <div class="C"></div>
          <div class="D"></div>
          <div class="E"></div>
          <div class="F"></div>
          <div class="G"></div>
          <div class="H"></div>
          <div class="I"></div>
        </div>
      </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Id tried to use col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 into html but didnt work;

Comment: https://cssgridgarden.com/ check this link it will help you to learn grid layout. instead of using px you need to use % or fr units to make it work. you are giving height width to the classes and also in container give it in container or in classes

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 2fr;
            grid-auto-rows: 100px;
            gap: 5px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }


        .container * {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        
        @media (max-width:1200px) {
            .container {
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width:1000px) {
            .container {
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr ;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width:600px) {
            .container {
                grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="A"></div>
            <div class="B"></div>
            <div class="C"></div>
            <div class="D"></div>
            <div class="E"></div>
            <div class="F"></div>
            <div class="G"></div>
            <div class="H"></div>
            <div class="I"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I exactly don't know what kind of layout you want but it's just for example

Comment: HI Nisha, so my code that I shared is my layout, my only issue is when I shrink my screen to mobile, the columns don't get responsive. For example, Column C and D could go under A and B when the screen is zoomed out or viewed from other devices such as smartphones.

Comment: your classes A B C D etc give them height and width again in media query where you think it not working properly

Comment: Please provide details in your answer, not only code.